# How to clear memory after submit form PHP

Tags: php

I have a code in PHP that received a variable, after that, with this variable I load inputs from a MySQL, so I need afterload that if the user changes some parameter update the database. My problem is when I send the update to the database, inputs(form) do not change but I see the change in the table on the table.

The code is like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT ... WHERE id = '".$_REQUEST["id"]."'");
        mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0);
        mysqli_free_result($result);                
        ?>
    <head>
        <title>FORM1</title>
        </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <form>
        <input type="submit" name="Ok" value="Ok"> 
        <input type="reset" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
        <br><br>
                    </form>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
$link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (isset($_REQUEST['Ok'])) {
        $UpdateData = "UPDATE ... SET ...WHERE id = '".$_REQUEST["id"]."'";
        mysqli_query($link, $UpdateData);
  
}
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question as it helps in being able to answer your question.

Comment: Your use of `$_REQUEST` instead of explicitly reading either `$_GET` or `$_POST` makes this hard to understand without additional context. Do you load this page with a query parameter (`id=123`)? If not, then you should be including the `id` in the `<form>` data, probably as a `hidden` value.

Answer (score 1):

You retrieve data before change them.You have to change the table then select new changes.
Move the PHP codes top of the HTML codes:

```
    <?php
    $link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") //Check if its POST req
   {
        if(isset($_POST['id']){$id=$_POST['id'];}

            $UpdateData = "UPDATE ... SET ...WHERE id = '$id'";
            mysqli_query($link, $UpdateData);
      
    }
        mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            $link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT ... WHERE id = '".$_REQUEST["id"]."'");
            mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0);
            mysqli_free_result($result);                
            ?>
        <head>
            <title>FORM1</title>
            </head>
                <body>
                    <div>
                        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="Ok" value="Ok"> 
            <input type="reset" name="Cancel" value="Cancel">
            <br><br>
                        </form>
                    </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this makes any difference.

Comment: I made some changes in my answer. Use $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" instead of $_REQUEST['Ok'];